# gitlab-runner pipeline failed clone with error port

Tags: git, gitlab

```
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Using docker image sha256:377f89d04c6a8215fcd5abcb918eb1efd3ef7d93aa02c4662942c9181cde01e9 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image php:latest ...
Using docker image php:latest ID=sha256:c8d1a5f14eb751e402a046d2b6424b041969af06b17db2cc8ea5a82fa343a593 for build container...
Running on runner-2ea396b6-project-1-concurrent-0 via vk-VirtualBox...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/gitlab/V1ki/ProductManager'...
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.1.93/gitlab/V1ki/ProductManager.git/' not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

`git clone http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@192.168.1.93:82/gitlab/V1ki/ProductManager.git /`  can success.

how to set up the port in gitlab-runner ?

.gitlab-ci.yml ？

Answer (score 0):

Check in your [Docker Executor configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) the spot where you define 192.168.1.93.

You could try simply to replace it with `192.168.1.93:82`: that would include the port number.

Comment: ` concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "productManager"
  url = "http://192.168.1.93:82/gitlab/"
  token = "2ea396b6e3375af166b11014a9b034"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache] ` here is my  /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml .

Comment: @user8540935 Is https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3091 relevant in your case?

Comment: `external_url 'http://192.168.1.93/gitlab/ ` here is my external_url at /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

Comment: @user8540935 Any chance to add the port in there?

Comment: nginx['listen_port'] = 82

Comment: Why is it looking for port 82 in your question, when the port is set to 80802? Oh: NGiNX, OK.